# What are dangling metacharacters in regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, metacharacters

In Ruby, I wrote a simple regex to find the first `{`:

```
txt.gsub! /^.*{/, '{'
```

Whenever I run this, everything past that point for my purposes works fine, however there is a mild error that reads along the lines of `WARNING: Dangling metacharacter detected.` What specifically are dangling metacharacters, and how would I change my regex to be as explicit and efficient as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{` has special meaning in regular expression.

```
PATTERN{m,n}
```

Above matches PATTERN repeated m~n times.

If you want avoid that warning (to match literally match `{`) escape it.

```
txt.gsub! /^.*\{/, '{'
```

**UPDATE**

BTW, `/^.*{/` does not catch the first `{` because `.*` is greedy match; It consume as much as possible.

Comment: So, dangling metacharacters are simply metacharacters that have not been set to escape?

Comment: @T145, Ruby regular expression is smart enough, so it will not cause error.  Maybe you're using some kind of syntax check, lint ??

Comment: Yes, I have a test suite set up to run in a development environment when certain actions occur. But, just so I know, that is what dangling metacharacters are?

Comment: @T145, As I mentioned in the answer, when `{` is used as meta character, it should be form of `PATTERN{m,n}`. For example: `\d{2,3}` to match 2 to 3 digits. In the `/^.*{/`, there's no numbers and no closing brace.

Comment: @T145, By the way, what tool (syntax checker, lint ..) do you use?